# Is it possible to stream data in python from Minio HTTPResponse directly to Popen.stdin without using Popen.communicate?

Tags: python-3.x, popen, minio

I'm trying to pass Minio.get_object to subprocess.Popen, which calls `age` crypto. Unfortunatelly, it seems the content gets somehow mangled and thus `age` fails.

Can't understand what am I doing wrong. I have the following code:

```py
with Minio(
    endpoint="endpoint",
    access_key="key",
    secret_key="secret",
).get_object(bucket_name="bucket", object_name="enc.py") as pipeIn:
    with subprocess.Popen(
        ["age", "--decrypt", "--identity", "./.age-ident", "--output", "-"],
        stdin=pipeIn,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    ) as pipeCrypto:
        pipeIn.auto_close = True
        pipeIn.decode_content = False

        retCrypto = pipeCrypto.wait()

        if retCrypto != 0:
            print(pipeCrypto.stderr.read().decode())
```

And I get `age: error: failed to read header: parsing age header: unexpected intro` and a bunch of hex

Doing things manually `mc cat bucket/path | age --decrypt --identity ./.age-ident --output -` works fine.
Using `Popen.communicate` also works fine:

```py
with Minio(
    endpoint="endpoint",
    access_key="key",
    secret_key="secret",
).get_object(bucket_name="bucket", object_name="enc.py") as pipeIn:
    with subprocess.Popen(
        ["age", "--decrypt", "--identity", "./.age-ident", "--output", "-"],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    ) as pipeCrypto:
        pipeIn.auto_close = True
        pipeIn.decode_content = False

        cryptoOut, cryptoErr = pipeCrypto.communicate(pipeIn.read())

        print(cryptoOut.decode())
```

`HTTPResponse` has `read` method so it should be OK to pass it as `stdin` to `Popen` or so I though, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I don't want to use `communicate` because

1. I'll have to store content in memory and the file can be quite large
2. I still need to pass output from `age` down to two more pipes, and so, those pipes need to use communicate too